# getting manager isn't available , auth.user has been swapped error in Django?

Tags: python, django

**Note**

Tried everything available on stackoverflow for solution but my error is not resolved

**my models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField('student status', default=False)
    is_creator = models.BooleanField('content creator status', default=False)


class Classroom(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=31)
    standard = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=STUDENT_STD, null=True, blank=True)
    division = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True, blank=True)
   

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # ExamSlot = models.ForeignKey(ExamSlot, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

**my view**

```
 from django.contrib import messages
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
    from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
    from django.db import IntegrityError
    from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, redirect
    from rest_framework import exceptions, generics, permissions, status
    from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
    from rest_framework.response import Response
    from rest_framework.views import APIView
    from .serializers import *
    from .models import Student
    from .forms import SignUpForm
    from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken, AccessToken
    from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    User = get_user_model()

def user_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

**my forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
# from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', )
```

**complete error**

```
AttributeError at /signup/
Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'student.User'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/signup/
Django Version: 3.1.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'student.User'
Exception Location: /home/dhruv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py, line 187, in __get__
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.8.10
Python Path:    
['/home/dhruv/Documents/assessment-folder/my-project-env/v1-16-assessment-portal-backend-Oct20 '
 '(1)/20211912FK-assessment-portal-backend-Oct20',
 '/home/dhruv/tutorial_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/dhruv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
 '/home/dhruv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/odf',
 '/home/dhruv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/odf',
 '/home/dhruv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/odf',
 '/home/dhruv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/odf',
 '/home/dhruv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/odf',
 '/home/dhruv/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/odf',
```

here is the complete error that django is rendering on the browser

I have added AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'student.User' in settings.py and i have used this model in my other files by using get_user_model() method but still gettng error `Manager isn't available Auth.user has been swapped with student.User`

Comment: Did you over ride the user model after you had already done a migration? Also can you post the stacktrace please?

Comment: No  i have overidden it from starting itself, verified it by deleting all the previous migrations

Comment: I'm sorry I got nothing. That stacktrace looks like it's missing the bottom, is that the whole thing?

Answer (score 1):

here is another method for importing `AUTH_USER_MODEL` instead of using `get_user_model()`

```
from django.conf import settings
user = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
```